# How to define location of gcov for CTest?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, gcov, ctest

I have a CMake/CTest configuration set up and all works fine. The problem is that we have one test runner that has several versions of GCC in use and for this project I'll have to use non-standard location of the compiler. So for example instead of using standard /usr/bin/gcc I'll be using /mnt/data/gcc/8.4.0/bin/gcc.

For compilation point of view everything goes well when using `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/mnt/data/gcc/8.4.0/bin/gcc` when creating the CMake project, but when I run `ctest -T coverage` CTest wants to use /usr/bin/gcov which is incompatible with the compiler. How can I set the CTest to use /mnt/data/gcc/8.4.0/bin/gcov instead?

I've tried to set the value of CTEST_COVERAGE_COMMAND in CTestConfig.cmake, but it does not have any effect.

Comment: Perhaps, you could try setting it via command line instead: `ctest -T coverage -DCTEST_COVERAGE_COMMAND=/mnt/data/gcc/8.4.0/bin/gcov`

Comment: No effect. I wonder does the CTestConfig.cmake file even get included. I got an impression from the documentation that it is included by default, but maybe not?